# Show empty value as &nbsp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a comment TextArea in my project that use to save a comments to the database and if the user is not insert any text i dont want it to show  &nbsp at the Project Comment details.

The saving code is : (p is a project object)

```
p.Comment1 = ProjectComments.InnerText.Trim();
```

The Preseinting code: (ProjectInfoComments is a textarea)

```
ProjectInfoComments.Value = row.Cells[6].Text;
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could `encode` an `" "` in your code using the `Server.HtmlEncode` method passing an empty space, for sample:

```
p.Comment1 = Server.HtmlEncode(ProjectComments.InnerText.Trim());
```

It will render the html code for specific chars like `<` `>` `&` `space` etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand you, but if you want to remove the `&nbsp` entity, simply use the `Replace` function:

```
 p.Comment1 = ProjectComments.InnerText.Trim().Replace("&nbsp;", "");
```